# Can I undo / correct my incorrect review of a question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I am relatively new in the review queue. Today I accidentally clicked "looks OK" to a question where I meant to click something else.

Is there a way that I can correct my vote / review on this, or at least remove my vote for that specific question?   Or should I not worry about it for now if it's the first time?

Comment: Point of clarification: the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32123031) this question is referring to is *not* an audit.

Comment: it is badly indented and should be edited, but else it looks ok

Answer (score 5):

What is the saying. Once is a mistake, twice is a coincidence, three times is a pattern.

Your vote is but one of several that is needed, so it is not a disaster. Just make sure it is a fluke and not something that you might trigger more often. For example if you managed to do this on your phone or tablet... maybe just not do reviews on those types of devices.

Comment: [Another variation](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/418466-once-is-happenstance-twice-is-coincidence-three-times-is-enemy) ([Ian Fleming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Fleming), *[Goldfinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldfinger_(novel))*):  *"[Once is happenstance. Twice is coincidence. The third time it's enemy action.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/418466-once-is-happenstance-twice-is-coincidence-three-times-is-enemy)"*. Or is that the original?

Comment: I was on a PC, I guess a twitch of the mouse finger. What I would *really* like to see is an (optional) confirmation dialogue, something I can set for myself. So that actions in review could ask me "Review XYZ as [ACCEPTABLE]. Please confirm".  I would still not get an option to edit later, but at least it would prevent some accidental mistakes.  (As has already been suggested over 2 years ago in linked question.)

Comment: @MyICQ no there is no reason to change the site functionality because you twitched in the wrong moment. The existing design is made exactly to be able to cope with individual boo boos.